# Why the Target Duration of the created segments are not the one i specified

Tags: http, ffmpeg, streaming

I am using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i Apple.ts -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list test.m3u8 -segment_format ts 'fileSequence%d.ts'
```

The files do get segmented but the values are not precise. see in the .m3u8 generated below the target duration is 12 but i specified 10

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOWCACHE:1
#EXTINF:11.478100,
fileSequence0.ts
#EXTINF:10.410400,
fileSequence1.ts
#EXTINF:11.745067,
fileSequence2.ts
#EXTINF:7.841167,
fileSequence3.ts
#EXTINF:8.024678,
fileSequence4.ts
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:12
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Also if i dont want the floting point duration how do i do it?

Comment: What is the GOP size for the input file? Can you post the complete console output for the command above?

Answer (score 1):

To get strict duration you need to ensure your input file has been encoded with a strict I picture rate.  Ensure you have set keyframe interval to 10 seconds and sc_threshold to 0 while encoding the original mp4.with ffmpeg. Then run your segmentation command. This will give you exact 10 second segments.
 Otherwise ffmpeg will try and cut around the 10 second mark ( or whatever duration you have given ) at the closes I picture it can find.

Comment: sc_threshold to 0, Why is it needed?

Comment: because scene cut detection will add I pictures whereever it detects a scenecut